# how to set context path in spring boot with spring security

Tags: spring-boot

I set contextPath in application.properties  as server.contextPath=/myWebApp  in spring boot application with spring security, default url as /login it not setting context path as /myWebApp  and redirect back me as /login not as /myWebApp/login. How to set contextPath with spring security 4.0 ? As tomcat give warning as context []..not deploying app in container.

Comment: Any suggestions on this problem? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by setting ***server.servlet.context-path*** in ***Application.properties*** file

Code Example

## Application.properties

**server.servlet.context-path=/myWebApp/**

---

with this, you can also achieve a login page as you want
http://localhost:8080/myWebApp/login

---

Comment: Correct way to change context path in Spring boot 2

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Boot you can set context path 3 ways.

**First in application.properties**  like as you do.

```
server.contextPath=/myWebApp
```

**Second  the change can be done programmatically as well:**

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CustomContainer implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {

        container.setPort(8181);
        container.setContextPath("/myWebApp ");

    }

}
```

**And Finally, by passing the system properties directly:**

```
java -jar -Dserver.contextPath=/myWebApp spring-boot-example-1.0.jar
```

**Spring Security Config is:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/index")
                .and()
                .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                ;

    }
}
```

And without any further  changes,tomcat will start automatically `/myWebApp/login`

Comment: what if we are deploying on external container. What class to use  instead of EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer ?