# Spring security - Change /login default path

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

We want to add spring to security to our spring boot application

The problem is that we have already `/login` path used already

So currently we can't load spring security default login page which redirect to `/login` path

We want to keep the spring default login form, just to change the path it uses,

Meaning, using the default behavior/implementation, only the default (form and process) paths need to be changed (without need to create html)

We didn't find any relevant [property](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.security) or code (or answer) to override it

I see in [DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/ui/DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java) the default

> ```
>  public static final String DEFAULT_LOGIN_PAGE_URL = "/login";
> ```

**EDIT**

Tried the `setLoginPageUrl` method suggested by @jannis

```
@Component
public class LoginFormFilter extends DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter {
    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        setLoginPageUrl("/api/login");
    }
    @Override
    public String getLoginPageUrl() {
        return "/api/login";
    } 
}
```

But still getting the default login page

Also failed to override using `loginPage` method

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
 ....formLogin().loginPage("/api/login");
```

Comment: Does this answers your question? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45140293/how-to-set-context-path-in-spring-boot-with-spring-security

Comment: @AjayKumar no, the context path is ok/shouldn't changed, just the login path of spring security

Comment: Try this then - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login OR this - https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.20.RELEASE/guides/html5/form-javaconfig.html

Comment: @AjayKumar it's a general tutorial, I prefer to use auto configuration, except login path, I'll check if it has some useful info, thank you

Comment: I'm not much into Spring recently but can't you use [setLoginPageUrl](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/bbf5614a9cb571b9a2a6968f94db18d47090e947/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/ui/DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java#L163) method to set the URL?

Comment: @jannis thanks, I checked it, and it helped, but still not working as expected

Comment: @user7294900 what do you mean? can you include the new problem in your post?

Comment: @jannis updated, basically I'm still getting the default login page

Comment: There is not a configuration setting for customising the default login page path because you are not expected to continue using that page. It is only there to get users up and running quickly. You can easily create your own login page that suits the look and feel of your application. The default page is just a Thymeleaf form that POSTs to "/login" styled with Bootstrap.

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana I want to use spring default page, the problem the path `/login` is used by my application

Comment: how about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50086521/2834978).

Comment: @LMC I want the default behavior/implementation, only the default (form and process) paths need to be changed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue in overriding default login url is in `FormLoginConfigurer` because that class is `final` and all useful configuration methods are `final` or `private`. Respectively, I propose to create additional configurer for setting properties in `DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter` class.

```
public class AdditionalFormLoginConfigurer extends AbstractHttpConfigurer<AdditionalFormLoginConfigurer, HttpSecurity> {

    private String loginPageUrl;
    private String loginProcessingUrl;

    @Override
    public void init(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter loginPageGeneratingFilter = http.getSharedObject(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.class);
        if (loginPageGeneratingFilter == null) {
            return;
        }

        loginPageGeneratingFilter.setFormLoginEnabled(true);
        loginPageGeneratingFilter.setUsernameParameter("username");
        loginPageGeneratingFilter.setPasswordParameter("password");
        loginPageGeneratingFilter.setLoginPageUrl(loginPageUrl);
        loginPageGeneratingFilter.setLogoutSuccessUrl(loginPageUrl + "?logout");
        loginPageGeneratingFilter.setFailureUrl(loginPageUrl + "?error");
        loginPageGeneratingFilter.setAuthenticationUrl(loginProcessingUrl);
    }

    public AdditionalFormLoginConfigurer loginPage(String loginPageUrl) {
        this.loginPageUrl = loginPageUrl;
        return this;
    }

    public AdditionalFormLoginConfigurer loginProcessingUrl(String loginProcessingUrl) {
        this.loginProcessingUrl = loginProcessingUrl;
        return this;
    }
}
```

And register the class above in the config like this:

```
private static final String LOGIN_PAGE_URL = "/custom_login_url";
private static final String LOGIN_PROCESSING_URL = "/perform_login";

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    ...
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage(LOGIN_PAGE_URL)
        .loginProcessingUrl(LOGIN_PROCESSING_URL)
        .permitAll()
    .and()
        .apply(new AdditionalFormLoginConfigurer())
        .loginPage(LOGIN_PAGE_URL)
        .loginProcessingUrl(LOGIN_PROCESSING_URL)
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security is based largely on Spring MVC. So, in order to change the default page (html and url) you need to do a couple of things:

**1. Add to your config:**

formLogin().loginPage("/whatever/path/to/you/login")

*formLogin* is the entry-point to customize form-based login behaviour, and loginPage overrides the default form. As stated on the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#formLogin()):

> Specifies to support form based authentication. If
> FormLoginConfigurer.loginPage(String) is not specified a default login
> page will be generated.

**2. Register a view under that new path to serve your custom form:**

registry.addViewController("/whatever/path/to/you/login");

**3. Include your new login form (html, thymeleaf, jsp, etc) into your resources.**

That should do the trick.

Here you are just overriding the URL and the form. Just keep in mind that here you are not overriding any of the other URLs for the login flow (like loginProcessingUrl).

There is also a good article on Baeldung: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login

Comment: we want to use the existing login page, without adding client side code

Comment: @user7294900 im sorry, i'm not sure if I got the question right then.

If all you need is to change the path, you can use the same technique, and paste the default login html on your resource folder.

To get the default html, you can have a look at the Spring class that generates it:
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter. The method is: generateLoginPageHtml

Comment: The problem is `DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter` use `/login` hardcoded which is already used by my application

Comment: Yes. Im not saying that you need to use programatically that class. 

You want to retrieve the HTML for the login form FROM that class, and paste it on your resources folder.

Then follow the steps above to override the Path and register the view.

Comment: Step 1. Override the login path. Step 2. Register the view. Step 3. get the HTML by hand from that class and paste it on a new file login.html. Step 4. put that file on the resource folder