# How to redirect login after expire session time? -Grails 4.x

Tags: grails, spring-security, session-timeout

I want to redirect `login/auth` when session time expired. How can I do that? Also I wanna set custom session time, like 1 min, 2 min etc.  Thanks

I'm using `Spring-security 4.x` and `Grails 4.x`

```
grails-app/src/session
```

Custom class

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .logout(logout -> logout
                        .logoutUrl("/logout")
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login/auth")
                        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                );
    }
}
```

After session expired getting this exceptions

```
2022-01-03 14:58:59.179 ERROR --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.g.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver   : NullPointerException occurred when processing request: [GET] /factoringnew/dashboard/index
Cannot get property 'id' on null object. Stacktrace follows:

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:211)
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:188)
    at org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.groovy:64)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsHttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsHttpPutFormContentFilter.groovy:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.groovy:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:64)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
    at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'id' on null object
    at factoring.BudgetViewDatabaseService.$tt__getConnectionInformation(BudgetViewDatabaseService.groovy:43)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:94)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
    at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:91)
    at factoring.BudgetViewDatabaseService.$tt__executeQuery(BudgetViewDatabaseService.groovy:320)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:94)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
    at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:91)
    at factoring.ExtraSettingService.getCompanyInfoMap(ExtraSettingService.groovy:901)
    at bv.DashboardController.setCompanyInfo(DashboardController.groovy:46)
    at bv.DashboardController.index(DashboardController.groovy:16)
    ... 40 common frames omitted
```

Comment: "I want to redirect login/auth when session time expired." - I think the plugin configures that to be the default behavior.  Which authorization method are you using?

Comment: "Also I wanna set custom session time, like 1 min, 2 min etc." - You can do that by setting the `server.servlet.session.timeout` config setting.

Comment: Hi @JeffScottBrown, I'm new here. As far as I know spring-security do it by default however it does not work. I do not use any customize authorization method/class.

Comment: maybe I could not explain you properly, can you help me? I'll be so happy if you give a suggestion

Comment: I updated the question. please see above....

Comment: Can you show whatever is at and around line 43 of `BudgetViewDatabaseService.groovy`?

Comment: Sorry Jeff for late reply,  around line 43,  

            `User user = User.findByUsername(username)
            def authUserId = user.getAt('id')`

Dosen't get `userID` couse of `session expire`

Comment: The stacktrace indicates that line 43 of `BudgetViewDatabaseService.groovy` is referencing a property named 'id' on a `null` reference.

Comment: Yes! because after `session timeout` the user goes `null` and in the meantime if system get any asynchronous request then system get the `error` but it should be redirect `logout`

Comment: Is `def authUserId = user.getAt('id')` at line 43?

Comment: "in the meantime if system get any asynchronous request" - I didn't realize that async was involved.  How are the asynchronous requests being initiated?

Comment: "How are the asynchronous requests being initiated?" - Suppose session is expired already then if I reload current page it happen, it could be any url like, `localhost:dashboard/index`

Comment: "Suppose session is expired already then if I reload current page it happen" - Are you doing that asynchronously?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240805/discussion-between-nocturnal-and-jeff-scott-brown).

Answer (score 2):

After session expiration, for new requests Spring will redirect the browser to login page("/login") by default, but if you want to change the login path (like "/my_custom_login"), I think [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68082468/) is a solution for that.

And for customizing session expiration time, you can implement a session listener like this:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;

public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

private int sessionExp_socconds=30;

@Override
public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    System.out.println("session created");
    event.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(sessionExp_socconds);
}

@Override
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    System.out.println("session destroyed");
}
}
```

Then you should define it as a bean in your SecurityConfiguration  class:

```
@Bean
public HttpSessionListener getHttpSessionListener(){
    return new SessionListener();
}
```